# How to distinguish between different BoxCollider in the inspector Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, components, inspector

Let's say I have a gameobject "player" with 4 different BoxColliders2D

I have a wall script that's a component of the "wall" gameobject.

The wall script has 4 different public boxcolliders2D variables, but I can't seem to find a way to set each of them to their respective boxcollider2D in the player gameobject, in the inspector.

Comment: I already know that your colliders are attached to child objects. Differentiate by child object's name.

Comment: I see, thanks, but just so I know, what if they were all set on the parent? Is there any way to differentiate via inspector?

Comment: Don't, as Programmer says in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The wall script has 4 different public boxcolliders2D variables, but I
>   can't seem to find a way to set each of them to their respective
>   boxcollider2D in the player gameobject, in the inspector.

You **can't** do that from the Editor but you should be able to do this via code.

Initialize your 4 variables from code by using the `GetComponents` function which returns array of components attached to the GameObject. Notice the 's' at the end. That's different from the `GetComponent` function which returns just one GameObject.

```
public BoxCollider2D col1;
public BoxCollider2D col2;
public BoxCollider2D col3;
public BoxCollider2D col4;

void Awake()
{
    BoxCollider2D[] colliders = GetComponents<BoxCollider2D>();
    col1 = colliders[0];
    col2 = colliders[1];
    col3 = colliders[2];
    col4 = colliders[3];
}
```

---

While the code version should work, do not attach multiple BoxCollider2D to one GameObject. What to do is create child GameObject for each extra collider you want then attach the BoxCollider2D component to it. This is the recommended way of using multiple colliders on one GameObject and that should solve your problem.

Below is a screenshot of what that should look like:

[image]

Now, you can drag each child Collider (*BoxCollider2D 1*, *BoxCollider2D 2*, *BoxCollider2D 3*) to the proper `public` variable name.